# Null Pointer Exception for Java Assignment

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have an assignment that I must take URLs in from a file (or standard input if no file is given) and then count the number of times the scheme is equal to certain things and when the domain is equal to certain things.

This is a part of my code that takes the input, splits it into the scheme and domain, and then increases variables if certain words are found. However, I keep getting `NullPointerException`, and I cannot figure out why. Right now, this code comes with an error at line 16. Any help would be appreciated.

```
File file = new File("input");
Scanner scan = new Scanner("input");
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!scan.next().equals("end") || !scan2.next().equals("end")) {
    if (scan.hasNext() == true) {
        url = scan.nextLine();
    }
    String[] parts = url.split(":");
    scheme = parts[0];
    schemeSP = parts[1];
    if (scheme == "http") {
        httpCt++;
    }
    if (scheme == "https") {
        httpsCt++;
    }
    if (scheme == "ftp") {
        ftpCt++;
    } else {
        otherSchemeCt++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < schemeSP.length(); j++) {
        if (schemeSP.charAt(j) == '.') {
            domain = schemeSP.substring(j);
        }
    }
    if (domain == "edu") {
        eduCt++;
    }
    if (domain == "org") {
        orgCt++;
    }
    if (domain == "com") {
        comCt++;
    } else {
        otherDomainCt++;
    }
    fileLinesCt++;
    totalLinesCt++;
}
```

Comment: Line 16 starting from the top of this snippet or line 16 in your general file? As far as I can tell line 16 in the snippet is `        else otherSchemeCt++;`, which is probably now what's giving you the exception.

Comment: on which line exactly do you get the NPE (double click on it to check it out) ? also, a small tip in order to avoid NPE on some cases, reverse the "equals" function parameters so that the constant will be the first one. for example: !"end".equals(scant.next()) . also, for checking if a string is equal to a constant, always use "equals"

Answer (score 2):

I'm noticing a particularly glaring problem.

```
File file = new File("input");
Scanner scan = new Scanner("input");
```

That `Scanner` is using the [`String` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29), **not** the `File` constructor.  I believe you had intended to do this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input"));
```

Without it, you're scanning on the word "input".

Furthermore, you're not comparing your `String`s correctly.  You always compare them with the  `.equals()` method.

Any statement like `scheme == "http"` should read `"http".equals(scheme)` instead.

Comment: I have updated the scanner line to what you suggested, but I have a couple of questions about this. I do not know what the name of the specific file will be so it needs to be able to take in any file. And then if no files are given it needs to take in lines through System.in. Will this line do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests like

```
if (scheme == "http")
```

Will always be false, because `==` compares identity - ie are they *the same* exact object.

Use `equals()` instead:

```
if (scheme.equals( "http"))
```

which does a *value* comparison.

Comment: How can you prove that scheme == "http" is always false? However the right method of comparing string is ofcourse equals method.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski The only way it could be true is if `scheme = "http";` happened first. Google "java string interning" and java == operator

Comment: That's of course true and I fully agree that the right solution is to use equals method. It doesn't prove that scheme == "http" is always false though. What about java String pool in this context?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski it is impossible to be ==. Strings don't work like that. The implementation of scanner doesn't intern returned strings. Only constants are interned.